# Effect of finite speed of light on timings of events

Tags: special-relativity

In relativity when an observer records an event some distance away from him, the timing of the event he measures would be different from what he would measure if he was close to the event as light would take some time to reach him. So when we say that he observes the event at time t(say) then is it according to what a different observer would measure who is at the same location as the event and whose clock runs like that of the first observer?

Comment: We assume observers are smart enough to have already taken into account the time it takes for light to travel to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In relativity when an observer records an event some distance away
>   from him, the timing of the event he measures would be different from
>   what he would measure if he was close to the event as light would take
>   some time to reach him.

This isn't true in Special Relativity (SR) - the *observed* time of an event *is* the time recorded by a (synchronized) clock *at* the spatial location of the event, and it is *not* the time that light from the event reaches the origin.

That is, *observing* is the not the same as *seeing* (or [photographing](http://users.monash.edu.au/~leo/research/movies/sr/sr-wmv.html)) in SR. From the Wikipedia article [Observer (special relativity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_(special_relativity)):

> The special relativity usage differs significantly from the ordinary
>   English meaning of "observer". Reference frames are inherently
>   nonlocal constructs, covering all of space and time or a nontrivial
>   part of it; thus it does not make sense to speak of an observer (in
>   the special relativistic sense) having a location. Also, an inertial
>   observer cannot accelerate at a later time, nor can an accelerating
>   observer stop accelerating.
>
> Physicists use the term "observer" as shorthand for a specific
>   reference frame from which a set of objects or events is being
>   measured. Speaking of an observer in special relativity is not
>   specifically hypothesizing an individual person who is experiencing
>   events, but rather it is a particular mathematical context which
>   objects and events are to be evaluated from. The effects of special
>   relativity occur whether or not there is a sentient being within the
>   inertial reference frame to witness them.

In summary, an (inertial) *observer* in SR is not a being with a definite location but is, conceptually, a system of unaccelerated rods and (synchronized) clocks at relative rest that assign space and time coordinates to each event.

Comment: Sir i read about theory of relativity ,what i understand is that time depends upon the speed with respect to reference as your approaches the speed of light time for you will get slow,sir i could not find find how the einstein relate time and speed

Comment: @yuvrajsingh, The oldest, and maybe the most intuitive explanation is Einstein's _[light clock](http://www.emc2-explained.info/The-Light-Clock/#.XVv7LOhKgUE)_. Even when you account for the time it takes signals from the clock to reach different observers, you _still_ must conclude that observers in different inertial reference frames see the clock "ticking" at different rates.

Comment: Still it is unclear for me that how einstein ,relate time and speed nature and how he thought that light is last limit of speed ,

Comment: Sir if tou agree yiu can move to chat ,let other also include in this topic

Comment: Thanks, so my assumption was correct it seems if I consider the observer to be the usual (Newtonian?) one.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh, Einstein did not _conclude_ that "light is the last limit of speed." He started his argument by _assuming_ that the speed of light was a universal limit. That assumption came from Maxwell's theory of "electromagnetic waves." Special relativity was Einstein's exploration of the consequences of Maxwell's theory.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that most observers would take into account the speed it takes the light to reach them, when they measure the time of an event. So, two observers with zero relative velocity to each other, but at different distances from an event, would measure the same occurrence time for the event (assuming they have synchronized clocks).